# TALES expression to compare numeric input in Plone?

Tags: plone, zope, ploneformgen

TALES expression is new to me. Can I get some good reference for the same? Actually I wish to define a content rule for numeric input field using ploneformgen. Something like:

```
python: request.form.get('amt', False) <= 5000
```

then apply the rule.

Here 'amt' is a numeric/whole number field on the input form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For reference, you should look at the official [TALES specification](http://wiki.zope.org/ZPT/TALESSpecification13), or refer to the [TALES section of the Zope Page Templates reference](http://docs.zope.org/zope2/zope2book/AppendixC.html#tales-overview).

In this case, you are using a plain python expression, and thus the normal rules of python code apply.

The expression request.form.get('amt', False) would return the request parameter `'amt'` from the request, and if that's missing, return the boolean `False`, which you then compare to an integer value.

There are 2 things wrong with that expression: first of all you assume that the `'amt'` parameter is an integer value. Even a PFG integer field however, is still a string in the request object. As such you'll need to convert in to an integer first before you can compare it.

Also, you fall back to a boolean, which in integer comparisons will be regarded as the equivalent of `0`, better be explicit and use that instead:

```
python: int(request.form.get('amt', 0)) <= 5000
```

Note that for a PFG condition, you can also return a string error message instead of boolean True:

```
python: int(request.form.get('amt', 0)) <= 5000 or 'Amount must be not be greater than 5000'
```

Comment: @SteveM: Thanks for the suggestion. :-) Better to use comments for that though, as you noticed altering answers is frowned upon on SO, however correct.

Comment: Thanx for the help. BUT what I actually want to do is depending on the input int value, if it is <=5000, want to move the saved data entry to folder1. If the input int value is > 5000 move it to folder2. I tried the above expressions but unable to resolve. Tried int('5000'),also python: int(request.form.get('amt', 0)) <= 5000

Comment: Perhaps it's not the condition that's wrong. Have you tried testing this with `python:True` and `python:False`?

Comment: On my local machine  content rule is working correctly, but on another machine same rules are not working correctly ??? :(

Comment: Check for your versions, and if they all check out, perhaps create a new question here on SO with all the details (full configuration for the conditions and actions).

Comment: actually I found out that TALES expressions for the content rules are not working for numeric fields !

Comment: plone.app.contentrules 2.1.6 plone 4.1 with the default zope. Same configuration works on my local system linux debian

Answer (score 1):

Usually form parameters are passed in as strings if they are not defined on the application level otherwise e.g.

Zope will under the hood use the fieldname amt:int in order to convert the value to an integer.

So you may want to try to put an int(....) around the first expression.